# Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.1' not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

How can I solve the issue of "Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.1' not found" ?

My pom.xml file loks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JavaDeveloperTask</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But it still gives me the error. What could be th cause of this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@ekm0d. I had the same problem using the `Intellij IDEA`. Here what I did and worked for me after inserting this on `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

1. Right-click on the project file.
2. Click on `Maven`
3. Click on Reload Project
4. Wait the `poem.xml` archive reload

I hope it works for you too :)

Comment: This worked for me in IntelliJ. "spring-boot-starter-validation" changed from red (not found) to grey.  Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.
Central repo have this dependency: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.5.1/

So i don't see why it should not work. Maybe there was some kind of network issue.

Try to remove it from local maven repo and download again.
You can find maven repo in your user home dir `.m2`, delete `.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.5.1` folder

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You should try to close the project and re-open it, the `dependency` will get downloaded by itself.

Worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had problems with the following two dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I didn't have to add anything, I just followed the steps suggested by @Emesson Cavalcante **and** one extra step:

1. Right-click on the project file.
2. Click on `Maven`
3. Click on Reload Project
4. Wait the `poem.xml` archive reload
5. Install plugins suggested by IntelliJ (when a popup appears)